# Emmet error PyV8 binaries (tried manual already)

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I've read the docs and tried to install the binaries manually by, both in

`C:\Users\Username\Sublime Text Build 3065\Data\Installed Packages\PyV8`

and

`C:\Users\Username\Sublime Text Build 3065\Data\Packages\PyV8`

I've tried the "For Sublime Text 2 (python 2.6) version and also the "For Sublime Text 3 (Python 3.3) version.  I am running python 2.7 so it should be the former, but I tried the latter just in case since it specifies 2.6 and not 2.7.

I continually get the same error despite following the instructions provided online.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is with Sublime Text 3083, latest emmet and Pyv8 binaries and Python 3.3.0 (it should work with latest Python also)

- Install Python and Sublime if you haven't done that yet! ;)
- Download emmet-sublime-master.zip at github. Forget Package-Control! In fact if you have emmet installed via Package Control just remove it.
- Go to: c:\Users-your user-\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\
- Create a 'Emmet' folder, respect the caps.
- Decompress the emmet-sublime-master.zip inside the Emmet folder.
- Download your pyv8 binary at github.
- Create a 'PyV8' folder (outside Emmet folder, c:\Users-your user-\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages).
- Inside PyV8 create a folder with the exact same name of the pyv8 binary you just downloaded (example: pyv8-win64-p3)
- Decompress the binary there.
- Restart Sublime Text 3.

It should work!